# A fair six-sided die is rolled 6 times. What is the probability of 5 and 6 appearing at least once?

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, dice

My approach was to calculate the probability of not throwing a 5 or a 6, and to time that by the number of throws. 4/6^6 = 0.09 and thus the opposing probability would be 91%. That, unfortunately, tells me only the odds of rolling a 5 OR a 6 in six rolls, not the wanted probability of 5 AND 6. How should I change my approach?

Comment: Hint: P(A∪B)=P(A)+P(B)−P(A∩B)

Comment: I used the first hint and the answer seems to make sense. P(A∪B)=P(A)+P(B)−P(A∩B), so In this case P(A∪B) = 1/6 + 1/6 - (1/6 * 1/6) = 0.3055 = 31%

Comment: @Kodtld: Please incorporate your comment into your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the event $A$ be "there are no '5' in 6 throws" and the event $B$ be "there are no '6' in 6 throws". Then the probability in question is:

$$1-P(A)-P(B)+P(A\cap B)=1-2\left(\frac56\right)^6+\left(\frac46\right)^6
\approx0.418.$$

Comment: what's wrong with my approach here? I see that you used the fact that $P(A \cup B)^c=P(A^c \cap B^c)=1-P(A \cup B)$. But isn't $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ since $A$ and $B$ are mutually independent? So this should be $1-2(5/6)^6+(5/6)^6(5/6)^6 \approx 0.4424$?

Comment: @Karam $A\cap B$ is the event "there are no '5' and no '6' in 6 throws". The probability of this event is $(4/6)^6$.

Comment: That makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

The [Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) says the probability that, after $n$ rolls, a $5$ and a $6$ have been rolled is
$$
P(n)=1-\left(\vphantom{\frac56^n}\right.\overbrace{\ \ \left(\frac56\right)^n\ \ }^\text{no $5$s}+\overbrace{\ \ \left(\frac56\right)^n\ \ }^\text{no $6$s}-\overbrace{\ \ \left(\frac46\right)^n\ \ }^\text{no $5$s or $6$s}\left.\vphantom{\frac56^n}\right)
$$
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|r}
n&P(n)&\%\phantom{00}\\\hline
0&0&0.00\\
1&0&0.00\\
2&\frac{1}{18}&5.56\\
3&\frac{5}{36}&13.89\\
4&\frac{151}{648}&23.30\\
5&\frac{425}{1296}&32.79\\
\color{#C00}{6}&\color{#C00}{\frac{9751}{23328}}&\color{#C00}{41.80}\\
7&\frac{23345}{46656}&50.04
\end{array}
$$

Comment: It is interesting how close to $50\%$ we get for $n=7$.